# What are the "Lawful" and "Chaotic" outsider equivalents of Aasimar or Tiefling?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, alignment

I intend to run a Pathfinder campaign that's more Law versus Chaos.  Good versus evil has been done repeatedly.

I am looking for existing monster entries for two things:

1. Humans with [axiomite](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/axiomite) (or other Lawful Outsider) blood in their ancestry.
2. Humans with [protean](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/protean) or (other Chaotic Outsider) blood in their ancestry.

Ideally I will also find PCGen data files for these monsters.

Yes, I could invent something and make up the PCGen data files.  I'm looking for existing precedent and work already done.  If that's not present, I will start making something myself... eventually....  I'd like to make a slew of what I will call "Axiomatic" and "Anarchic" characters.  If you look at the Tiefling, Aasimar and other examples below, the d20pfsrd pages have side bars on how to create characters with these templates.  That's what I'm looking to see if has already been created.

As examples of something similar that already exists, the d20pfsrd and other places state: "[Tieflings](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/tiefling) are humans with demonic, devilish or other evil outsider blood in their ancestry." and "[Aasimars](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/aasimar) are humans with a significant amount of celestial or other good outsider blood in their ancestry."

There are other examples of what I'm getting at.  The d20pfsrd also states: "[Undines](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/undine) are humans whose ancestry includes elemental beings of water, such as marids."  It also states: "[Sylphs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/sylph) are humans whose family trees include elemental beings of air, such as djinn."

I am *not* looking for variants of Aasimars nor variants of Tieflings.  I don't want stats for a Lawful Good Aasimar.  I'm looking for Lawful Neutral outsider stats.  The Aaasimar, Tiefling, Sylph and Undine are provided as examples.

It's a Pathfinder campaign so ideally I would find not only the term but also the monster stat block that will go with the Pathfinder rules.  The campaign is not set in the Pathfinder world Golarion so the answer does not have to be tied to the Golarion setting.

This question has been edited and updated per comments and suggestions from other RPG SE members.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I would suggest merging your two questions into one.  They're not really significantly different, and I think you'd get more complete and useful answers from both at once than one at a time.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl I appreciate your suggestion WRT merging.  One reason I opened two questions was that a lot of people wind up on rpg.se after a Google search.  Someone searching for "Lawful -Chaotic" (as in "I want Lawful creatures, not Chaotic" might be less likely to find the question.  A second reason is that specific questions tend to get more specific answers.   With that in mind, if my Question and Answer get voted down enough that I qualify for the Peer Pressure badge :-) I'm sure I will reconsider.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl Another minor point: I did try to find an answer on my own before posting here.  I did search the d20pfsrd for an answer to my questions, as well as the Pathfinder wiki and a few other sites.  I found the reference to Axians as  Lawful Neutral outsiders, but nothing for Chaotic Neutral outsiders.  Since I found a reference to one alignment but not another, this difference led me to post two different questions.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl questions merged.  Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### *Pathfinder* lacks an exclusively chaotic or exclusively lawful planetouched, but *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* has both

While an [aasimar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-aasimar) or a [tiefling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tiefling) can *also* be lawful or chaotic, it sounds like you want planetouched creatures that are *primarily* lawful or chaotic with the good and evil secondary. On that front, I've no reason to doubt DuckTapeAl's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/85017/8610) is correct: *Pathfinder* doesn't have the races you want yet. (However, I expect that—having realized this gap—it will shortly.) *But* if you're willing to go back to *Pathfinder*'s antecedent and do a little conversion, such creatures were published for *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*.

Travis Stout's *Dragon* #297 (July 2002) article "Children of the Cosmos: 8 New Planetouched Races" (62-6), in addition to other similar creatures, includes statistics for the planetouched races the axani and the cansin, humanoid-in-appearance panetouched outsiders like the aasimars and tieflings except that they're creatures of "order and entropy" (according to the subhead), respectively. In addition to minor traits like skill bonuses similar to the aasiamr and tiefling, the axani can use a [*calm emotions*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/calm-emotions) effect 1/day and possess cold and sonic resistance 5, while the cansin can use an [*entropic shield*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/entropic-shield) effect 1/day and possess acid and fire resistance 5. The creatures, to the best of my knowledge, go unmentioned in any other publications.

While not designed for *Pathfinder* specifically, converting the creatures to *Pathfinder*—even from *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*—, given the creatures' similarities to the traditional planetouched, should be easy. However, because the creatures are unsupported by any further lore (receiving *maybe* 400 words each, and that's including racial traits), a GM hoping to have a well realized pair of races like the aasimar and tiefling for his campaign is out of luck unless he's willing to create such lore himself.

Comment: Wow.  A Dragon article from 2002?  I bow before your 3rd ed knowledge. :P

Comment: @DuckTapeAl Hey, *you* went through every *Pathfinder* monster. Respect.

Comment: @HeyICanChan  Yes, I am looking for planetouched creatures that are primarily  Chaotic with this question.  Both the name, and stats block, and ideally someone else has already done the PCGen data file set up.   While I *can* do that myself, I'm happy to learn someone else has already done that work.

Answer (score 3):

Such a creatures doesn't exist.

It's hard to prove a negative, but I did a number of searches through the PFSRD trying to find anything that resembles what you're asking for, and I couldn't find anything.  I've never encountered anything like what you describe in my years of playing both 3.5 and PF, and I don't think anything like that exists.

The main reason why I don't think there is a chaotic or lawful version of the Aasimar or Tiefling is that the PF bestiary is a lot more focused on the good/evil spectrum, and not the law/chaos one, as you note in your question.  Axiomites and Proteans are new to Pathfinder, and don't even show up until the Bestiary 2.  There are entire books about Tieflings and Aasimars (Blood of Fiends and Blood of Angels, respectively), so if chaotic or lawful equivalents existed, it's likely that they would be easier to find.

All that aside, it would be pretty trivial to make Lawful and Chaotic planetouched creatures, using Tieflings and Aasimars as the base.  You'd have to reflavour some things, but the Advanced Race Guide has a lot of guidance on how to modify and create new races.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just recently asked a similar question on Reddit, and while I haven't been able to find anything for a lawful race, I was able to find the Xax by Alluria Publishing (third party):

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/alluria-publishing/xax

... And someone showed me a link to the Ganzi (apparently Paizo materiel?), who aren't technically 'born' from an outsider race like tiefling or aasimar, but are plane-touched like them:

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/more-races/race-points-unknown/ganzi

Personally, I think the Xax are cooler and more "chaotic," but they look strange and alien, and might not fit into your game as well as a Ganzi. Either way, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The [Distant Shores Gazeteer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015QL52QE) presented us with the [Ganzi](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/more-races/race-points-unknown/ganzi), which are humanoids with chaos-infused blood. While not technically halfbreeds like tieflings or aasimars, they do share similarities with them, like being **outsiders** with the **native subtype**.

> Unlike the crossbreed aasimars and tieflings, ganzi are mutations caused by generations of **exposure to chaotic energies** in the Material Plane.
>
> Ganzi share many traits with proteans. They are fluid and flexible, resilient, resistant to the energies of decay and entropy, and can sense the delicate currents of chaos that bind the planes together, alerting them to danger and deception and allowing enterprising ganzi to stir those eddies and rewrite a creature’s fortunes. They also share the proteans’ curiosity and disdain for order, compulsively wandering the world to see what can be seen.

Answer (score -2):

## **Yes, there are chaotic versions for both Aasimar and Tiefling.**

For Aasimars: **Azata-Blooded** *(Musetouched)* and **Garuda-Blooded** *(Plumekith)*

For Tieflings: *Demodand-Spawn* *(Foulspawn)*, **Demon-Spawn** *(Pitborn)* and **Qlippoth-Spawn** *(the Motherless)*.

You can find this information about Aasimar with Chaotic ancestry in the book **[Blood of Angels](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8sa7?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Blood-of-Angels)**. There is also Tieflings with Chaotic ancestry in the book **[Blood of Fiends](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8qzz)**.

Comment: You have not answered the OP's actual question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The question was about humans with chaotic outsider ancestry, not Aasimars that are chaotic good instead of neutral good.